# Authenticated encryption (Symmetric encryption) for .NET applications

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, .net, integrity

Is there an implementation of [Authenticated encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) for .NET applications?

The [AES API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx) from .NET does not include mode such as **GCM**. In the documentation, I can only see insecure modes [(ECB, CBC, OFB, ...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ciphermode(v=vs.110).aspx) that can not be use alone.

**Very important** : I am looking for a *mature* implementation not a GitHub project used by 1 person or an old/dead project.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely use [bouncy castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/).

Comment: The only thing that bother me is that it was not updated since 2011. "Release 1.7, 7th April 2011" Either it was not review or their was never a security vulnerability found.

Comment: It's fairly wide used in production code implying that its also sufficiently secure.

Answer (score 0):

There are several libraries that allow for authenticated encryption in .NET.

[Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/), mentioned in an earlier answer, is not.   Microsoft itself offers an open source library that is quite low-level, just wrapping the CNG APIs that offer authenticated symmetric encryption in Windows, called [CLR Security](https://clrsecurity.codeplex.com/).

The CLR Security library is going to be the most mature library you'll find, but it is low level, and so can be used incorrectly.  I have written a higher-level library wrapping CLR Security called [Cryptocore](https://github.com/xandersherry/cryptocore) which exposes a SimpleEncryption API.  It won't meet your maturity requirement, but you should at least review it to see how to use CLR Security properly.

Comment: Sorry, but CLR Security and Cryptocore does not meet the "maturity" requirement.

Comment: @h3xStream Then you're out of luck.  There isn't anything more mature than CLR Security, or more widely used than Bouncy Castle.